# How to Inherit Single Property from parent bean to child bean

Tags: spring

Here?In my Spring code all properties are inherited but i need only address property in to my child class

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="baseEmployeeBean" class="com.java.beans.BaseEmployee">
        <property name="company" value="Java2novice" />
        <property name="address" value="mumbai" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="myEmployeeBean" class="com.java.beans.Employee" parent="baseEmployeeBean">
        <property name="empId" value="1016" />
        <property name="name" value="Nataraja Gootooru" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Why does the parent have both company and address if all you want to do is inherit the address?